# Joining multiple tables in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Data JPA and facing problem in joining two tables.

I have two tables: `Product` and `Type`.

`Product` has fields as `product_no`, `name`, `cost`, `type_id`.

`Type` has fields `id` and `name`. I'm able to pull data from `Product` table but not able to display `Type` name along with product details. The tables with data are as follows:

```
Table : product

id      product_no  name                     type_id
1       kts2018        Kites tracker         1
2       jt2018           Jira  tracker           1
3       st2018          Strike seeker         2

Table:  type

id       name
1        Tracker
2        Seeker
```

The entities are as follows :

Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_no")
    private String product_no;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    private Type type;


    public String getProduct_no() {
        return product_no;
    }

    public void setProduct_no(String product_no) {
        this.product_no = product_no;
    }

    public Level getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
```

Type

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type")
public class Type implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

I am using the below code to pull data from product table:-

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

    @Query("select product, product.type.name FROM Product product where product.type.id=1")
    List<Product> getAllUserProducts();
}
```

The controller is as follows:-

```
@GetMapping("secure/product-details")
    public ModelAndView getAllUserProducts() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("userProducts", userInfoService.getAllUserProducts());
        mav.setViewName("products");
    return mav;
}
```

products.html

```
<tr th:each="product: ${userProducts}">
                                    <td th:text="${product.product_no}"></td>                                                                           
                                    <td th:text="${product.type.name}"></td>

                                    <td><a class="btn-info btn-sm" style="border-radius: 4px"
                                        th:href="${'/show/' + product.product_no}">Process</a></td>
                                </tr>
```

Now I am getting Thymeleaf errors.

It says

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "product.product_no"
```

Comment: So, how does your data look like then? Can you show the contents of your tables with relevant data?

Comment: And your where condition `where product.type=1` in the query looks strange. Is "1" an Id of the Type Table?

Comment: *not able to display Type name along with product details*: please be explict: what code do you use to display the type name along with product details, what do you expect that code to do, and what does it do instead. If it causes an error, the post the exact and complete error message.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic  Updated with relevant table data

Comment: Try to change `where product.type=1` to `where product.type.id=1`

Comment: @mrkernelpanic  Please see the updated question. Now the query is generated but getting Thymeleaf errors. Kindly help

Comment: Your query doesn't return a List<Product>. It returns a List<Object[]>. To return a List<Product>, it should be `select product FROM Product product`, not `select product, product.type.name FROM Product product`. If you select two things, you get back arrays containing two things.

Comment: Yes, selecting product and using product.type.name in the template gave me the desired result. So, if I need to join two or three tables, then I just need to place the mappings correctly  and display required column values in template, right? Pl correct me if I am wrong.